# Descendants in styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

In styled components imagine I have

```
let Nav = styled.div`
  height: 50px;


  ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
`
```

what is the difference if I do:

```
let Nav = styled.div`
  height: 50px;


  /* just added & */
  & ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
`
```

What is difference between 1st and 2nd?

For example if I use **1st**, then in such case

```
<Nav/>
<div>1 <ul></ul></div>
```

the styles will also apply to `ul`? But if I used 2nd styles would not apply to `ul`?

Answer (score -1):

For that be apply styles to 'ul', use from second code(& ul). But in your JSX, you have to edit like this:

```
<Nav>
    <div>
      1 <ul></ul>
    </div>
</Nav>
```

Because, when you use from ( & ul ), then **'ul'** must be a **child** of **'Nav'**.

If this helped you, please tell me.